# Url.RouteUrl in razor page is retrurning null or empty url .NET5.0 .NET Core3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-5

My code is working fine in MVC 5. Recently I created new project in .NET Core (.NET 5.0) using visual studio 2019 and in razor view

```
@Url.RouteUrl("ChildrenWithCulture", new {  action = "FormControlsPartial", pid = pid })
```

is returning empty
This is route configuration in Startup.cs

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "ChildrenWithCulture",
    pattern: "{culture}/{controller}/p/{pid}/{action}/{id?}",
    defaults: new { action = "Index" });

// Url.RouteUrl() in razor view i am using inside javascript
// code to call the page through ajax.
```

Answer (score -1):

In .net core,we usually use `Url.Action`,here is an official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-5.0).You can try it.Here is a demo:

```
$(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("ChildrenWithCulture", new {  action = "FormControlsPartial", pid = 1 })';
            console.log(url);
        })
```

result:

[image]

Comment: It didnt work for me. Result is same. Also I didnt see Url.Action parameters contains route name

Comment: You are using .net core 5,right?Do you have any error?

Comment: No error. Just it is returning empy in javascript like this
var url='';

Comment: Why do you use `action = "FormControlsPartial"` and then also use `.Action("ChildrenWithCulture"`?Which one is the action you want to set?

Comment: ChildrenWithCulture is route name. Action name is FormControlsPartial
As I mentioned in question, same code is working in MVC 5 correctly. Only in this .NET Core project, it is not working.
When I try to execute same statement in controllers code, while debuging, it shows following error
The expression cannot be evaluated.  A common cause of this error is attempting to pass a lambda into a delegate

Comment: What is your route of controller action?If you want to get `{culture}/{controller}/p/{pid}/FormControlsPartial/{id?}`,you can use `@Url.Action("FormControlsPartial", new { pid = pid })`.